# Pass value object to entity method

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

its good practice to pass value object to entity methods (in terms of DDD)? 
For example I have a method in my entity Customer:

```
SetAddress(Address invoiceAddress);
```

is it valid? Or I should pass address parameters as

```
SetAddress(string street, string town, string zip, string country);
```

and let the customer handle the creation of address object and if needs throw an exception.

Address is immutable object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely pass an `Address` object. It is valid in terms for DDD and it's also good for extensibility (i.e. you can add more fields to `Address` object without changing the signature of the `SetAddress` method).

Also the `Address` object should contain validation logic for address information, which a `Customer.SetAddress(...)` method can execute before setting the address:

```
public class Customer
{
    public SetAddress(Address invoiceAddress)
    {
        // ToDo: Execute validation logic encapsulated in 'Address' object
        // ToDo: Execute additional validation logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From an Object oriented point of view, the three arguments of `SetAddress()` represent the `Address` hence should be encapsulated into an instance of the `Address` class. Though I am not sure why you have a method to perform `SetAddress`, can't you use a `setter` instead?

In case, your `SetAddress()` is publicly available, then the caller of the method does not have to worry about 3 incoherent string arguments. More importantly the order of the arguments cannot be determined by looking at the function name (`SetAddress()` does not provide any information whether the arguments are in the order: street, town, zip, country or street, town, country, zip). It is easy for the caller to confuse the order of the arguments.

To avoid such scenarios, it is best that `SetAddress()` accepts an argument of the type that is clearly indicated in its name i.e. an instance of `Address`.

Comment: as i undrestood it can break the immutability of address object.

Comment: You can design the `Address` instance such that it does expose the setters for the town, zip, etc and initialized only via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a factory method as part of Address

```
public class Address
{
    public static Create(string street, string zip)
    {
        return new Address { Street = street, Zip = zip };
    }
}
```

The idea being that the params for `Create` show what are the mandatory properties for creating an Address object.

```
var address = Address.Create("street", "zip");

customer.SetAddress(address);
```

Comment: in address I have defined constructor with parameters so I think the result from this is the same. my question : is the customer class responsible for creating the address VO or should i just pass it to method. thanks for post.

Comment: In short, the Customer would not be responsible for creating an Address. Only the Address knows what is valid address looks like.